# What activity lifecycle method is called when the user switches off the monitor

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I have an android activity. If the user switches off the monitor of the android device for some time and then switches back on again, It seems like that the current activity is restarted. I found an activity lifecycle picture on the Internet but it does not tell me what method is called when the user switches off the monitor. It only tells me that when the activity is running, and "another activity comes in front of the activity", the `onPause()` method is called. But a "black screen" is not "another activity", right?

So what is called when the device's monitor is switched off?

Comment: `onStop()`, I believe.

Comment: `onPause`, then `onStop`

Comment: Why don't the developers include this in the lifecycle picture?

Comment: Look at the pic at my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onPause` will be called first, then `onStop` will be called

[image]

Comment: And let me guess, `onRestart` is called when the user switches on the monitor. Am I right?

Comment: Pls note that if switch on the screen, `onRestart` called only your activity is visible (I mean that after locked screen passed)

Answer (score 1):

Activity lifecycle methods and state

```
onResume() called- Visible
onPause() called - Partially Visible
onStop() called - Invisible
```

If app is in memory, then onRestart call when app starts again, otherwise onCreate() called

Comment: It's already visible when it's in Started. In Resumed state, it's visible and on foreground which means it's interactive.